# Racket: Why wont this compile?

Tags: racket

I'm attempting to program a simple function that adds integers to a list descending from a range of "high" and "low", incremented by "step"

For example,
if the input is (3 12 3), the expected output is '(12 9 6 3)

Below is the following code:

```
(define (downSeries step high low [(define ret '())])
  (if (< high low)
      ret
      (cons ret (- high step))
      (downSeries (step (- high step) low))))
```

I'm pretty new to racket, but I'm really not sure why this isn't compiling. Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Since only racket is tagged and no special languages are describes it is expeted the first line in the definition window is `#lang racket`. Answer will be different for student languages.*

1 The last argument is nested in two parentheses and is illegal syntax. Default arguments only have one set:

```
(define (test mandatory (optional '()))
  (list mandatory optional))

(test 1)   ; ==> (1 ())
(test 1 2) ; ==> (1 2)
```

2 You have 4 operands in your `if` form. It takes maximum 3!

```
(if prediate-expression
    then-expression
    else-expression)
```

Looking at the code you should have the `cons` expression in the position of `ret` argument. Having it before the recursion makes it dead code. `ret` will always be `()`. Eg this loks similar to a typical fold implementation:

```
(define (fold-1 combine init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init                             ; fully grown init returned
      (fold-1 combine 
              (combine (car lst) init) ; init grows
              (cdr lst))))
```